# How can i run my alarm when the app is completly closed in Android (Kotlin)

Tags: java, android, kotlin, alarm

Im creating a custom alarm app, and this means i have to run  a piece of code (for example calling an Intent so it open a screen where i can stop the alarm). What is the best way to achieve this?

I tried it with  the Alarm Manager and used

```
<receiver android:name=".receiver.AlarmReceiver"
        android:process=":remote"></receiver>
```

in the Manifest File

In my code i call this

```
  var alarmManager = context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
    val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java)
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0)
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, pendingIntent )
```

10000 because i wanted to test it, if it gets called after 10s

Is this the best way to do an alarm clockapp?

Answer (score 0):

simple "yes" is too less for answer on SO, so I can only add that exact alarms are draining battery more than inexact, so use both types with respect to user. still, for alarm clock app broadcast calls should be exact, so go on with that solution

also, from [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager):

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have your application code run at a specific time, even if your application is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks, timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

and also note a change since API19 (if you want to support such old):

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, android.app.PendingIntent) and setExact(int, long, android.app.PendingIntent). Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.